# How to build and add a child component in React using React Top Level Api's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I am trying to load react in the script tag so exploring the React top levels api's. I would like to achieve an equivalent of

```
render() {
    const { trowserOpen, item ,organizer, requestId, intl, onClose } = this.props;
    return (
      <Parent
        autoFocus
        history={false}
        onClose={this.handleCloseTrowser}
        open={trowserOpen}
        title={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'trowserTitle' })}
        dismissible
      >
        <Child
          item={item}
          organizer={organizer}
          requestId={requestId}
          onClose={onClose}
        />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}
```

How can i build the Parent react component and inject the Child react component into it at runtime using React's Top Level api (using non jsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.createElement once you have added React to script.

Something like this :

```
React.createElement(
  'div',
  [props],
  [React.createElement(
    'div',
    [props],
    [...children]
  )]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way of converting your JSX into pure JavaScript. Use [Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwBQhgTgpgdgLgKAAQtSsBXOB7AYtgYwwGdk1UALAS2JwgE8BeAbwDMwAbYqAXzPKTYYAYQ7ZuLONWIA6CmBgATDlFHioAFQjYA7twh8BKbAAdYk7XqgQA8mZiGjcKnBUsq8DjNbYIAWzA4AFkoYmIwAHMoAApmJCpFAC4kAHI4S30NFxUUpB4ASkcBRRo_GmIqACMVflQAPlq0YGFqDkVG8hcoP3c4bqKjXwiFKgAvaxYhkfGDDrRoAEcMULgASUUWReXadYGBITUJZgOxbj3UAHoGgWAL8Gh4OqA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.15.3&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D). So you can just copy paste your JSX there and get the Javascript back.

Make sure React is checked in the Presets.